# Advanced Custom Fields - If/Else Statement with true/false checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have added a true/false checkbox using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress. I want to be able to select an option which amends the page template.

I am adding this option to the Product Category in WooCommerce / Wordpress. I have included this bit of logic in the code.

I have the following code but it does not work. I suspect it is because it is not within the loop. However the code I want to insert includes the loop. Any ideas/guidance on the code is much appreciated

```
<?php if (is_product_category() && get_field('field_name') == true) { ?>

    <div class="custom-sidebar-right">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>                 
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div>

<?php } elseif (is_product_category() && get_field('field_name') == false ) { // Added close brace

<div> Empty Test </div>
}
```

Comment: "field_name" you are using this one as custom field, I mean the name or is it something else, also try dumping the value var_dump ( get_field('field_name')  ); ??

Comment: Thanks. field_name is the custom field. I have set this correctly in my code. Not sure about var_dump - sorry!

Comment: var_dump is just to check what value you are getting

Comment: doh! I get: bool(false)

Comment: That just means your field value is not updating when you are saving your data to database.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've now fixed this and will post the answer in 6 hours time - I'm a new user so can't answer straight away. The var_dump was super useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I re-read the docs for ACF and found the following (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/how-to-get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/)

So I applied with some logic and now it works. Thanks for var_dump pointer as that helped me fix this.

```
// vars
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;  

$is_field_name = get_field('field_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);

if (is_product_category() && $is_field_name == false) { ?>
```

Comment: Is this also for inside loop and just outside the loop ?

Comment: Should be fine for either as in the second brackets of get_field we set where ACF needs to look. If that second bracket is not included then it will look within the current loop.

Answer (score 0):

missing bracket in the if statement ,
change

```
  if (is_product_category() && get_field('field_name') == true)
```

with

```
if (is_product_category() && get_field('field_name') == true) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I'm afraid that doesn't work, but it did point out that I had missed a bracket on the if statement above, which I've now fixed/

Comment: `if (is_product_category() && get_field('field_name') == true) )`

Comment: Brackets fixed but not solved. I can get the different output from changingg == true or == false for get_field('product_cat_two_col_template') - It seems that get_field('product_cat_two_col_template') is always false. I thought it might be because it is out of the loop.

Comment: what do you want to do with is_product_category(), are you trying to check if that is set or not ?

Comment: tbh is_product_category() is not relevant, i added it as i wanted to check with multiple params. is_product_category() is working well and is true if on product page. My problem lies with the get_field('field_name') from ACF. This is a true/false selector i have added to the product categories. From within the product category I can set this. I then want to use this within my IF statement, but it is always false.

Comment: remove `is_product_category() &&` and check if it is true